# Footer Isn't Getting a Background Color?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I'm putting links to Facebook and Twitter at the bottom of a webpage I'm creating but the footer isn't getting the background color I want it to get. Here's the HTML code behind it:

```
<center>
<div id="footer">
<a href="#" title"website on facebook"><b>facebook</b></a> <a href="#" title"website on twitter"><b>twitter</b></a>
</div>
</center>
```

And here's the CSS code I've got:

```
.footer {
width:100%;
height:60px;
background-color:#3399FF;
}
```

Anyone know why there's no background color appearing?

Comment: is something overriding your css. check developer tools. comes handy in such kind of cases.

Comment: offtopic but one quick tip. In HTML5 center tag is not supported. You should use add css selector `text-align: center;` in the footer css and remove the center tag wrapped around your div. Additionally, you should look into `<footer>` tag (http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_footer.asp)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because you've used a wrong CSS selector.

periods `.` are used to select elements with a certain class. While you set an id attribute to the div, you need to use `#` mark, to select the element:

Try this one:

```css
#footer {
  width:100%;
  height:60px;
  background-color:#3399FF;
}
```

Read more on: **[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Getting_started/Selectors)**.

Answer (score 1):

Use class="footer"

```
<center>
<div id="footer" class="footer">
<a href="#" title"website on facebook"><b>facebook</b></a> 
<a href="#" title"website on twitter"><b>twitter</b></a>
</div>
</center>
```

Or change in CSS

```
#footer {
width:100%;
height:60px;
background-color:#3399FF;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You Have used wrong selector to apply css.

If You will use `Id` then use `#` and if you use `class` then use `.` selector to apply css.

if you use :

```
<div id="footer">
//text
</div>
```

then use :

```
#footer {
width:100%;
height:60px;
background-color:#3399FF;
}
```

and if you use :

```
<div class="footer">
//text
</div>
```

then use :

```
 .footer {
    width:100%;
    height:60px;
    background-color:#3399FF;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

change it to # id from . class

```
#footer {
width:100%;
height:60px;
background-color:#3399FF;
}
```